# How to create a numpy array without having a specified number of elements?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to create a numpy array that can hold integer values, without knowing a priori how many integer values it can hold. However, I do know the maximum number of integer values that may be held.

With lists, I just create an empty list, and append to the list as and when a new 'suitable' number is found. However, I cannot do such a thing with an array. The closest I have is to create a zero array using `np.zeros(N)`(with N being the max possible number of integers) but then changing elements to the required number as and when needed. However, the problem with this is that I will still have zero elements, which I cannot delete/pop off, like I can with lists.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: what's your goal? Why not use a list?

Comment: Why can't you append to numpy array? Is this what you're looking for https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html ?

Comment: You can read all the numbers into a list first, then convert that to an array.

Comment: @dm2, do not recommend `np.append`.  It is evil, a poorly named and conceived copy of the list append.

Comment: @hpaulj did not know that, thanks for the info :)

Comment: To the comments suggesting I use a link or convert a link to an array, I use numba which is a just in time compiler to get shorter runtimes. That does not work if my program has lists. I actually study physics, and I have learnt python on my own so I might be wrong about numba, but in my experience when used with a list it has failed to compile

Comment: Appending to a list and creating an array at the end of the loop is the most widely suggested approach.  List append is relatively fast.  But seriously, do you have to select these integers one by one?  To get any decent `numpy` speed you want to look at the problem as a whole, not iteratively.  In beginning physics they teach us to think in terms of 'vectors', not the individual coordinate values.  Similarly in `numpy` we should think about arrays and whole-array operations.

Comment: delete and pop are easier and faster with lists.  Arrays have a fixed size.  Adding or removing elements makes a whole new array, copying values from the old.

Answer (score 0):

'Arrays' are supposed to be a fixed length data structure which is why you might not be able to find a direct solution to your problem.

It is even better if you make a list and convert it into numpy array.

```
arr=[]
for i in some_list:
    arr.append(i)
x=np.array(arr)
```

x is your numpy array now.

Comment: This should probably just be an edit to your other answer.

Comment: I use numba which is a just in time compiler to get shorter runtimes. That does not seem to work if my program has lists.